# Spring Data/Hibernate/JPA join by non-primary keys

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

There are two related entities **Account** and **AccountInfo**. These entities connected by non-primary keys (number_ff, number_ff2). I see that Hibernate fetching three entities(Account, AccountInfo, AccountInfo) by one sql query. But I see that hibernate do additional query to database as well. Why does hibernate do additional call(query2)? How to avoid it?

Also I tried to use JPQL query. It works the same way (2 sql queries).

Database schema(postgres):

```
CREATE TABLE public.accounts (
    user_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    number_ff varchar NULL,
    username varchar(50) NULL,
    number_ff2 varchar NULL,
    CONSTRAINT accounts_pkey PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);
CREATE TABLE public.account_info (
    account_info_id serial4 NOT NULL,
    number_ff varchar NULL,
    info varchar(1000) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT account_info_pkey PRIMARY KEY (account_info_id)
);
```

Hibernate enitity 1:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "accounts")
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Account implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long userId;
    @Column(name = "number_ff")
    private String numberFf;
    @Column(name = "number_ff2")
    private String numberFf2;
    private String username;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "number_ff", referencedColumnName = "number_ff", insertable = false, updatable = false, unique = true)
    private AccountInfo accountInfos;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "number_ff2", referencedColumnName = "number_ff", insertable = false, updatable = false, unique = true)
    private AccountInfo accountInfo2s;
}
```

Entity 2:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account_info")
@Getter
@Setter
public class AccountInfo implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long accountInfoId;
    @NaturalId
    @Column(name = "number_ff")
    private String numberFf;
    private String info;
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class ServiceInfo {
    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Optional<Account> account = accountRepository.findById(1L);
        System.out.println(account);
    }
}
```

SQL queries: Query 1 (Query that retrieves all the necessary data)

```
select
    account0_.user_id as user_id1_1_0_,
    account0_.number_ff2 as number_f3_1_0_,
    account0_.number_ff as number_f2_1_0_,
    account0_.username as username4_1_0_,
    accountinf1_.account_info_id as account_1_0_1_,
    accountinf1_.info as info2_0_1_,
    accountinf1_.number_ff as number_f3_0_1_,
    accountinf2_.account_info_id as account_1_0_2_,
    accountinf2_.info as info2_0_2_,
    accountinf2_.number_ff as number_f3_0_2_
from
    accounts account0_
left outer join account_info accountinf1_ on
    account0_.number_ff2 = accountinf1_.number_ff
left outer join account_info accountinf2_ on
    account0_.number_ff = accountinf2_.number_ff
where
    account0_.user_id =?
```

Query 2: (Additional query, why does it do it?)

```
select
    accountinf0_.account_info_id as account_1_0_0_,
    accountinf0_.info as info2_0_0_,
    accountinf0_.number_ff as number_f3_0_0_
from
    account_info accountinf0_
where
    accountinf0_.number_ff =?
```

I think second call is redundant. Why does hibernate do additional call (**query 2**)? How to avoid it? It looks like bug for me.

Please see small project on GitHub: [github link](https://github.com/DzmitryNev/hibernate-issue-non-primary-keys)

Comment: Turn on parameter logging; the number_ff value should tell you which relationship is involved and hint at what might be happening. Try removing one of the two relationships and see if it is related to having the same join to the same table.

Comment: Why are you joining on number_ff ? You should join with the primary key.

Comment: I know about joining by primary keys but I need to use non-primary keys (example it could be isbn).